# What is the default value for Guid?

Tags: c#, .net, guid, default-value

The default value for `int` is 0 , for `string` is "" and for `boolean` it is false. Could someone please clarify what the default value for `guid` is?

Comment: default `Guid`  is `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`. It's basically binary zeroes.

Comment: related question [How can I default a parameter to Guid.Empty in C#?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5117970)

Comment: This website can supply empty guids http://00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.com/

Comment: As a side note: the default value of strings is null, not "" (;

Answer (score 209):

You can use these methods to get an empty guid. The result will be a guid with all it's digits being 0's - "`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`".

```
new Guid()

default(Guid)

Guid.Empty
```

As Use Keim points out in the comments `default` is short for `default(Guid)`

Comment: In newer C# versions, `default(Guid)` and `default` are the same, too.

Comment: Guid.Empty can't be used as a compile time constant. So you can't use it to default a parameter.

Answer (score 54):

You can use `Guid.Empty`. It is a [read-only instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the Guid structure  with the value of `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

you can also  use these instead

```
var g = new Guid();
var g = default(Guid);
```

beware not to use `Guid.NewGuid()` because it will generate a new Guid.

use one of the options above which you and your team think it is more readable and stick to it. Do not mix different options across the code. I think the `Guid.Empty` is the best one since `new Guid()` might make us think it is generating a new guid and some may not know what is the value of `default(Guid)`.

Answer (score 31):

The default value for a GUID is empty. (eg: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)

This can be invoked using `Guid.Empty` or `new Guid()`

If you want a new GUID, you use `Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: @anchor I've noticed that you have never accepted any answer to your questions. [Here - in the FAQ of StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) you can read how you can accept an answer and why you should do that.

Comment: @Genhis I think he got what he needed and then dropped of the face of the earth haha

Answer (score 12):

To extend answers above, you cannot use Guid default value with `Guid.Empty` as an [optional argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) in method, indexer or delegate definition, because it will give you compile time error. Use `default(Guid)` or `new Guid()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an **Empty Guid** or **New Guid** using a class.

The default value of Guid is **00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000**

```c#
public class clsGuid  // This is a class name
{
    public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    clsGuid cs = new clsGuid();   
    Console.WriteLine(cs.MyGuid); // This will give empty Guid "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

    cs.MyGuid = new Guid();
    Console.WriteLine(cs.MyGuid); // This will also give empty Guid "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

    cs.MyGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    Console.WriteLine(cs.MyGuid); // This way, it will give a new Guid (eg. "d94828f8-7fa0-4dd0-bf91-49d81d5646af")

    Console.ReadKey(); // This line holds the output screen in a console application
}
```

Comment: yes...you can make the class value as static value...or using that in class..

Comment: I know we can use Guid as we can use any other type in C#. My question was, whether your answer contains any new information that wasn't here before. It seems  all the information you posted was already posted by multiple other people years ago.

Comment: yes...u r right...i telling that...u can use empty guid and new guid using a class...that type of answer is not present...in this question...

Comment: Formatting could be improved, specifically the comments should start with //.  Otherwise this is a good answer as it specifically displays usage in a custom class.